# Import an external library into a ROS node

Tags: c++, external, libraries, ros, catkin

It is my first time using stack overflow so I am a bit new with this. I've been working on a personal robotics project and I have downloaded a GitHub directory. I've already compiled it, tested it (it works) and I've generated the `library.a` file (because I'm working with Ubuntu 16.04 and ROS Kinetic). What I do not know is what I have to add to my `CMakeLists.txt` file in order to load the communication functions on a ROS node cpp file.

My actual description for compilation on the `CMakeLists.txt` file is the following one:

```
...
add_executable(test_node src/test_node.cpp)
add_dependencies(test_node ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(test_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
...
```

I know that I have to add the library on the target_link_libraries if the library was an `*.so`file, but it isn't. What should I add to my `CMakeLists.txt` file in order to load my library functions into my ROS node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is based in a property on function **add_library()**

See this example block:

```
add_library(library_name STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(library_name PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION path/to/your/lib.a)
```

With this you can proceed to add this library with:

```
target_link_libraries(your_target library_name)
```

But don't forget to add this static library include files to your target.

---

The problem is solved with the following code:

```
...
find_package(Threads)
add_library(github_library STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(my_library PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION 
my_library_directory/my_library.a)
...
target_link_libraries(my_cpp_ros_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES} my_library ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
...
```

Comment: but if your static library can be compiled externally, i recommend checkout the use of this `ExternalProject_Add()` this could be more useful and handy.

Comment: It starts to compile but there are some compilation errors because of how is made the library. Could it be any compatibility issue because my library is compiled using a `Makefile` and my ROS project uses a `CMakeLists.txt`? I don't think so, but the compilation error is the following one: `undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5`

Comment: Could you please suggest me an easy example of use about ExternalProject_Add()? I'm a bit new in programming with CMake and documentation can be a bit confusing.

Comment: (1) if you compiled your ROS project with another build system, it will broke. But i think that you forgot to link to p thread: `target_link_libraries(your_target library_name p_thread)`
(2) if you have a git repository for this project i can write a example of use to you.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much, I'll edit your answer if you dont mind to update with the solution.