# Linking a prebuilt binary in cpp does not work?

Tags: c++, cmake, ros, catkin

I just build the following package: [faiss](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/releases/tag/v1.5.3) and my cpp program now recognises all library header so I can include them into my program. But my programm throws `undefined reference to`. So when I built faiss it created a **libfaiss.a** and a **libfaiss.so** which one to link and how??? I think I have tried any solution that I could find in the internet, but my knowledge of the build/linking process is limited.

My Faiss build-directory looks like this:

```
faiss-1.5.3/
  -libfaiss.a
  -libfaiss.so
  -foo.h
  -foo.o
  -foo.cpp
  -bar.h
  -...
```

My tries. (I am using **ROS, catkin_simple and gtests**)
So this is how I would usually do it:

```
find_library(LibFaiss faiss HINT /home/tim/faiss/faiss-1_5_3/faiss-1.5.3/)

catkin_add_gtest(test_inverted_nn test/test_inverted-nn.cc
                 WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}})
target_link_libraries(test_inverted_nn ${LIBRARY_NAME} ${LibFaiss})
```

I get the following Error:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lLibFaiss-NOTFOUND}
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> CMakeFiles/test_inverted_nn.dir/build.make:358: recipe for target '/home/tim/catkin_ws/devel/lib/nn/test_inverted_nn' failed
> make[3]: *** [/home/tim/catkin_ws/devel/lib/inverted_nn/test_inverted_nn] Error 1

I also found this Solution here [Import an external library into a ROS node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58085079/import-an-external-library-into-a-ros-node), but that does not work for me:

```
add_library(libfaiss STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libfaiss PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION /home/tim/faiss/faiss-1_5_3/faiss-1.5.3/libfaiss.a)
target_link_libraries(test_inverted_nn ${LIBRARY_NAME} ${libfaiss})
```

This throws the following Error:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l}
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

****EDIT****
After correcting the not_found error I am getting the following error:

> CMake Warning at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/test/gtest.cmake:180 (add_executable):
> Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target
> test_inverted_multi_index because files in some directories may conflict
> with libraries in implicit directories:

```
runtime library [libz.so.1] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
  /usr/local/lib
```

Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.

*** It does not matter what I add inside `target_link_libraries` I am always getting that error***

****EDIT2****
So with the tipp of @Aconcagua I deleted everything from the CMakeLists.txt and only added the following to my cmake options:

```
-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-L/home/tim/faiss/faiss-1_5_3/faiss-1.5.3/
```

But Im still getting the undefined reference errors. It does not make any difference

Comment: Have you told ld where to find the libraries? You do that with `-L` flag...

Comment: Have you checked that `find_library` is succeeding? Calling it twice is a little odd,i think the second will overwrite the result of the first

Comment: @AlanBirtles Wow sorry that was a typo here in Stack. In my code I am calling it once. How do you check if find_library succeeded?

Comment: @Aconcagua No! Tell me more? I thought my Hint would do that? And is there a problem that the same path has the .a and .so? Like does it know which to choose

Comment: The first error message is about `find_library` which doesn't find the library (note on `NOTFOUND` in the library name). Both error messages are also about the extra `}` at the end of `target_link_libraries` call.

Comment: thanks @Tsyvarev I fixed that and got a new error complaining about libz.so.1 my conflict

Comment: @Emilio7773 Relevant are the `.a` files, the `.so` files are loaded at runtime. `-L/path/to/libraries`, the path can be absolute or relative to working directory. You can specify that multiple times, one parameter for every directory where such a library you link against resides in.

Comment: @Aconcagua thanks! I somehow get still some undefined references.

Comment: @Emilio7773 Undefined references means you are not linking against a yet necessary library (i.e. there's yet another `-l`, minuscule L, parameter lacking) – or against yet another object file of yours. This differs from libraries not found where you need another `-L`.